# Filter input to remove certain characters/strings

Tags: bash, sed, awk, sh

I have quick question about text parsing, for example:

```
INPUT="a b c d e f g"
```

```
PATTERN="a e g"
```

INPUT variable should be modified so that PATTERN characters should be removed, so in this example:

```
OUTPUT="b c d f"
```

I've tried to use

```
tr -d $x
```

in a for loop counting by 'PATTERN' but I don't know how to pass output for the next loop iteration.

edit:
How if a INPUT and PATTERN variables contain strings instead of single characters???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure Bash using parameter substitution:

```
INPUT="a b c d e f g"
PATTERN="a e g"

for p in $PATTERN; do
  INPUT=${INPUT/ $p/}
  INPUT=${INPUT/$p /}
done
echo  "'$INPUT'"
```

Result:

```
'b c d f'
```

Comment: Works with strings too, gr8 solution.

Answer (score 3):

Where does `$x` come from? Anyway, you were close:

```
tr -d "$PATTERN" <<< $INPUT
```

To assign the result to a variable, just use

```
OUTPUT=$(tr -d "$PATTERN" <<< $INPUT)
```

Just note that spaces will be removed, too, because they are part of the $PATTERN.

Comment: This $x was orginally my counter in for loop: <pre>for x in $PATTERN; do
echo $INPUT | tr -d $x 
...
done</pre>

Your solution is quite good, but forgot to mention that I dont know at the beginning how many chars $PATTERN will have, but Yours good for 3 chars..