# how to delete line which contain some specific string in shell

Tags: grep

Plz help me to delete line which contain `/` or `ab` in linux shell
Example:

```
ghkl
aaaabd
fdkh/dfd
hjnh
```

after filter : we got:

```
ghkl
hinh
```

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Filter input to remove certain characters/strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185181/filter-input-to-remove-certain-characters-strings)

Comment: @itsjeyd I do not see how this related to the post you are linking to.  Different questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '!/\/|ab/' file
ghkl
hjnh
```

---

Using `grep`:

```
grep -v "/\|ab" file
ghkl
hjnh
```

`-v` inverts the action to not print line with this pattern

---

`'!/\/|\?/'` 
`'` start of awk command
`!` a not, do do not find this
`/` start of regex find whats between / and /
`\` escape the next character so its not treated as a command
`/` since this is escaped find this `/` 
`|` or. Find this or this
`\` a new escape to prevent ? used as code
`?` since escaped find `?`
`/` end of regex
`'` end of awk command

Comment: thanks ,why it doesnt work if i do with awk '!/\/|?/' file .When i want to change ab to ?

Comment: Try to escape the `?` like this `awk '!/\/|\?/' file`

Comment: you did a great help .can you help me to understand a bit about awk '!/\/|\?/' file , can you explain .Thanks

Comment: my confuse was: '!/\/|\?/'

Comment: See my updated post.  If you like it, please accept it, check mark to the left of the post.